How to know the classname for unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns
I got the warning message from Google Play Console after uploading APK. It is about unsafe encryption pattern.
See image
I tried the below steps, but it did not help me.
1.Increase the AES key length from 128 to 256.
2.Check source code with the link https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9450925
3.Remove BC Provider from the source code
4.Use javax.crypto.KeyGenerator and android.security.* to do encryption and decryption.
All the above steps are not able to get rid of the warning message.
If I know the name of vulnerable class, it will help me better.
How can I know name of the vulnerable class b.d.a.b.L ?
